# Me falla SQL en servidor Nginx - Pantalla en blanco

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, nginx

Buenas hace unas semanas me puse a instalar un servidor con Nginx, además con php 5.6 y php 7.2.

Hasta ahora me funcionaba todo correcto, pero hoy solo con poner en el código un `<?php include "conexion.php"; ?>` ya se me queda en blanco la pantalla.

**Esto es conexion.php**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'usuario', 'pass', 'nombreBD');

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Alguien me puede ayudar, no se muy bien qué puede pasar? gracias.

Comment: ¿ese es el fichero tal cual? te faltaría abrir php:   `<?php`

Comment: Hola @Fly no, falta datos aquí que no los veia necesarios, el problema parece estar en el php 5.6, porque en el 7.2 si que funciona

Comment: ¿y que mas falta? deberías poner el código tal cual lo estés usando. El problema seguramente esté en tu código no en php 5.6 ;)  ¿hay mas includes? ¿que dice el log de errores? ¿no puedes aportar más información?

Comment: Todo lo demás esta bien, no hay más código, solo faltan las llaves de php y código html, al ponerlo en PHP 7.2 funciona perfecto